# Specs test with Fakeapplication fails with access to play.Cache -> no application present

Tags: playframework-2.0, specs2

I have a setup like this:

```
class PriceAwareSpec extends Specification  {

 sequential

 running(FakeApplication()) {

 val price = "CHF 50.00"
 val priceAsHtml: Html = Html(price)

 val context: Context = ContextAccessUtil.getContext
 val stateAccess = ServiceFactoryUtil.getService(context, classOf[StateAccess])

 "price aware template" should {

   "per default" in {

    stateAccess.store(StateKeys.HIDE_NETTO_KEY, java.lang.Boolean.FALSE)

     "show netto" in {
       val html = views.html.price.priceAware(priceAsHtml, true)(request)
       contentAsString(html) must contain(price)
     }

     "show brutto" in {
       val html = views.html.price.priceAware(priceAsHtml, false)(request)
       contentAsString(html) must contain(price)
     }
   }
 }
}
```

With the call to

```
ContextAccessUtil.getContext
```

There is an access to the play Cache with a

```
play.cache.Cache.get("foo")
```

which does try to get the information from the current application (=FakeApplication() ?)

This results in a NullPointerException:

```
[error]       NullPointerException: null (Cache.scala:-1)
[error] play.api.cache.Cache$.get(Cache.scala:57)
[error] play.api.cache.Cache.get(Cache.scala)
[error] play.cache.Cache.get(Cache.java:16)
```

This is indicating that there is no Application present....?!

Is there something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on the [Play 2.0 wiki](http://bit.ly/UpZKGu) the contexts have to be created for each example:

```
"Computer model" should {

  "be retrieved by id" in new WithApplication {
    val Some(macintosh) = Computer.findById(21)

    macintosh.name must equalTo("Macintosh")
    macintosh.introduced must beSome.which(dateIs(_, "1984-01-24"))  
 }

 // or, if you want to be more specific about your configuration
 "be retrieved by id" in new 
    WithApplication(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {
    ...
 }
```

}

This makes sure that each example is executed in the context of a `FakeApplication`. On the other hand what you have done in your code is surrounding the *creation of the examples* with a `FakeApplication` which has no impact on their execution. Note that the next version of Play 2.0 should have [an even easier version](http://bit.ly/Sco9QZ) for what you're trying to do:

```
class MySpec extends Specification with ApplicationExample {

  // only override if necessary
  implicit override val app = 
    FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = Map("foo" -> "bar"))

  "something" should {
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot convince the compiler to handle the example 'in new WithApplication'. Neither did the mixing trait of ApplicationExample work. I'm working with Play Version 2.0.4