# Play framework specs2 url testing

Tags: playframework, specs2

I'm trying to figure out how to test multiple URLs in the Play framework using specs2 and I can't seem to figure out the proper way to do it without starting multiple servers.

```
import org.specs2.mutable._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.libs.ws.WS

class testServer extends Specification {

  running(TestServer(9000)) {
    "Server starts" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
    "Who" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000/url1").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
    "How" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000/url2").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
    "Why" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000/url3").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
    "Test4" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000/url4").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
    "Test" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000/url5").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
    "Help" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000/url6").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
    "Bogus" in {
      await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000/url7").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489818/specs-test-with-fakeapplication-fails-with-access-to-play-cache-no-applicatio). You need to create a new context for each example. For instance you can write:

```
import org.specs2._
import execute._
import specification.AroundExample

class testServer extends Specification with AroundExample {
  def around[R <% Result](r: =>R) = 
    running(TestServer(9000))(r)

   "Server starts" in {
     await(WS.url("http://localhost:9000").get).status must equalTo(OK)
   }
   ...
}
```